# Boost build instructions for windows/codeblocks, help sought

Tags: boost

I got windows 7 x64, was dl'ing the windows 7 .net 4 sdk when I figured out how to build the bjam.exe file after failing to fulfill these instructions

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef#Set_up_a_Code::Blocks_global_variable_for_Boost

but when I run bjam, I still get a failure.

these are the steps I did

had to add 
f:\codeblocks\mingw\bin
to path
THEN open command prompt as administrator (not before path)
then run from boost_1_51_0\tools\build\v2\engine\build.bat

then I could do

```
bjam --toolset=gcc "--prefix=<installpath>" install
```

but I get this message when I do

```
F:\libraries\boost_1_51_0>bjam --toolset=gcc "--prefix=f:\codeblocks" install --
build-type=complete
warning: mismatched versions of Boost.Build engine and core
warning: Boost.Build engine (bjam) is 03.1.18
warning: Boost.Build core (at F:/libraries/boost_1_51_0/tools/build/v2) is 2011.
12-svn
F:/libraries/boost_1_51_0/tools/build/v2/util\path.jam:476: in path.makedirs
rule MAKEDIR unknown in module path.
F:/libraries/boost_1_51_0/tools/build/v2/build\configure.jam:190: in configure.s
et-log-file
F:/libraries/boost_1_51_0/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:725: in load
F:\libraries\boost_1_51_0\tools\build\v2/kernel\modules.jam:283: in import
F:\libraries\boost_1_51_0\tools\build\v2\kernel\bootstrap.jam:142: in boost-buil
d
F:\libraries\boost_1_51_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

almost looks like linux path's are getting scrambled into the mix

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I redownloaded the bjam that was in the instructions, dumped it to the f:\libraries\bjam folder I had initially setup.

set path=f:\libraries\bjam yadad;%PATH$ whatever command

cd to boost_1_51_0 dir

reran build command

to actually get something to build
I had to add this to other linker options
or , you have to add "$(#boost.lib)\libboost_system-mgw44.lib"  into "Other linker options".

source
http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=11908.5;wap2