# Boost build via Codeblocks, windows

Tags: boost

I got boost built following some instructions from earlier

[Boost build instructions for windows/codeblocks, help sought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832895/boost-build-instructions-for-windows-codeblocks-help-sought)

but now I get this weird error when I try to compile

undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6thread12start_threadEv'|

all I want to do is use the boost threading...

this guy had the same problem (it's in French)

http://www.siteduzero.com/forum-83-603401-p1-lib-boost-thread.html

Comment: how the f do people ever learn to program when there's roadblocks like this all the time?  Seriously, 3 days I've been working on getting the "simple" version of threading to work on my windows installation....

Comment: Patience. Three days is _not_ a long period of time to debug a problem.

Answer (score 0):

solved
in codeblocks, this fixed it

settings
compiler & debugger
linker settings
add

```
F:\CodeBlocks\lib\libboost_regex-mgw44-1_51.a
F:\CodeBlocks\lib\libboost_thread-mgw44-mt-1_51.a
F:\CodeBlocks\lib\libboost_chrono-mgw44-1_51.a
f:\codeblocks\lib\*.a
```

depends on libraries needed, which depends on your #includes